# Is it good to change the Python antigravity library

Tags: python, python-antigravity

I came across Python's antigravity library recently and got information about it from [this](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/import-antigravity.html) post. I then tried `import antigravity` in the interpreter: it opened the URL of the xkcd comic as expected but did not display the image of the comic in that page.

I then found that the comic did not show up because the URL in the antigravity library was a HTTP one and when I tried to load the page after changing the URL from http://xkcd.com/353/ to https://xkcd.com/353/ the image showed up.

This made me think if this could be corrected. Is it good to report this as an issue in the Python code (or) change the following line in the antigravity library :

```
webbrowser.open("http://xkcd.com/353/")
```

to

```
webbrowser.open("https://xkcd.com/353/")
```

and submit as to their Issue tracker.

What would be the consequences of the above change? Would it cause any backward compatibility issue?

### Edit

Just for the Note. This problem has been fixed after filing an issue in the Python Bug Tracker. You may find the issue using [this link.](https://bugs.python.org/issue28181)

Comment: Using python2.7 my antigravity library uses http and it works fine.

Comment: Works for me. Tried Python 2 and 3 on Ubuntu. Perhaps something wrong with your ISP?

Comment: @gecko You may right about that, because the network I am connected to uses Cyberoam to filter websites (and content maybe). I didn't know it would filter contents alone instead of filtering the websites completely. I should have thought of it before asking this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Report it to the Python issue tracker. Its purpose is to get questions like "will there be problems with backward compatibility" into the view of the people best capable of making that determination. Even if they reject the change, the issue will be documented, in case a later review reverses that decision.